# SpringBoot fail to create an Instance of class based on JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have problem with Spring boot.
Here is controller

```
public void addNewWatcher (@RequestBody WatcherInput input) {
        boolean isDeptIDExist = false;
        boolean isCourseIDExist = false;
        for(Department department : manager){
            if(input.getDeptId() == department.getDepartmentID()){
                isDeptIDExist = true;
                for(Course course : department.getCourses()){
                    if(input.getCourseId() == course.getCourseID()){
                        isCourseIDExist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!isDeptIDExist || !isCourseIDExist){
            throw new RESTFileNotFound("deptID or courseID do not exist");
        }

        try {
            Course course = manager.get(input.getDeptId()).getCourse(input.getCourseId());
            ApiCourseWrapper selectedCourse = new ApiCourseWrapper(input.getCourseId(), course.getCatalog());
            ApiDepartmentWrapper selectedDepartment = new ApiDepartmentWrapper(input.getDeptId(), course.getSubject());

            ApiWatcherWrapper newWatcher = new ApiWatcherWrapper(nextWatcherID.incrementAndGet(), selectedDepartment, selectedCourse);
            watchers.add(newWatcher);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

WatcherInput

```
public class WatcherInput {
    private int deptId = 0;
    private int courseId = 0;

    public WatcherInput() {
    }

    public WatcherInput(int deptId, int courseId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public int getDeptId() {
        return (int)deptId;
    }

    public int getCourseId() {
        return (int)courseId;
    }
}
```

The problem is "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `API.WrapperClass.WatcherInput` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (11); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `API.WrapperClass.WatcherInput` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (11)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",

I think the SpringBoot cannot create an Instance of WatcherInput, but i dont know why

Comment: Do you have the setter written? It can also impact the workings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making the `int` types `Integer` instead? It seems like it's having problems deserializing one of the numbers.